# Migration of SQL Server 2012 database to Oracle 12c

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, oracle12c, dbmigrate

I'm trying to migrate a SQL Server 2012 database backup file, which I wanted to migrate to Oracle 12c. I tried to use SQL Developer tool for migration using this reference:
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/hol08/sqldev_migration/mssqlserver/migrate_microsoft_sqlserver_otn.htm

The problem is in SQL Developer tool, I didn't see any option where I can generate database capture script for SQL Server 2012, because there is no option which is showing up there.

[image: See screenshot]

I'm open for other suggestions as well. the SQL Server is installed on my same system, where I've installed Oracle 12c, so even if there is way by which we can directly connect with SQL Server on my local system.

Answer (score 0):

Hello for migration from SQL SERVER to Oracle. There are many articles are available on web. You can google it. For as one reference use [this](https://taliphakanozturken.wordpress.com/2012/11/29/migration-from-sql-server-to-oracle-using-sql-developer/) article and try for migration of data.